# Как сформировать модель Pydantic?

Tags: python, json, pydantic

Есть вот такой простенький ответ от сервера:

```json
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "query",
                "status"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'ACTIVE', 'BANKRUPT', 'CLOSED'",
            "type": "type_error.enum",
            "ctx": {
                "enum_values": [
                    "ACTIVE",
                    "BANKRUPT",
                    "CLOSED"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

На его основе создана JSON-схема (это я для постмана сделал. Нормально валидируется):

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "detail": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "loc": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {"type": [ "string", "integer" ]}
            },
            "msg": {"type": "string"},
            "type": {"type": "string"},
            "ctx": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "enum_values": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {"type": [ "string", "string", "string" ]}
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "enum_values"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": ["loc", "msg", "type", "ctx"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "detail"
  ]
}
```

Пытаюсь создать модель Pydantic, но пока никак:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List

class Data_from_detail(BaseModel):
    loc: list[str, int]
    msg: str
    type: str
    ctx: List[str] = ["ACTIVE", "BANKRUPT", "CLOSED"]

class Detail(BaseModel):
    detail: list[Data_from_detail]
```

Comment: ctx должен содержать в подобъект с полем enum_values со списком строк, а у вас там сразу список.

Comment: Я создал enum:
class Company_stats(Enum):
    ACTIVE = "ACTIVE"
    CLOSED = "CLOSED"
    BANKRUPT = "BANKRUPT"

Но вариант с:  ctx: Company_stats Тоже не проходит

Comment: Вот такое я имею в виду: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn7JM.png Сайт: https://jsontopydantic.com

Comment: Да я вроде писал и такой вариант тоже.. Спасибо огромное за сайт. Сейчас буду смотреть.

Из-за вот этого падала валидация: loc: list[str, int], но я искал проблему в этом enum.
Еще раз Спасибо! И за сайт отдельно! =)